# Laravel display pdf from path which is in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have read so many questions and blogs about this but cannot solve my problem. So I am uploading a pdf and it's path is stored in a database like this:

```
E:\laravel12\public\pdf/1577916921.pdf
```

I am displaying the image like this:

```
<iframe src="{{$pdf->data}}"  height="500" width="500" style="margin-Top :200px;"></iframe>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/laravel12/public/pdf/1577916921.pdf
```

How can this problem be solved?

Controller:

```
if ($req->hasFile('fpdf')) {
    $mime = "aaa";
    $image = $req->file('fpdf');
    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('pdf');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $content = $destinationPath."/".$name;
    $up = new Picture();

    $up->name = $name;
    $up->mime = $mime;
    $up->data = $content;

    $up->save();
}
```

Comment: You should not save `$pdf->data` with local path, must a public url.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur for example ?

Answer (score 0):

public_path uses the disk path, not the URL path, so I suggest you store the name only without the full physical disk location, and whenever you want to display it you can use the url() function to generate the URL

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet which shows your solution in more details?

Answer (score 0):

don't save full path in database

save after public path in database
like this

**pdf/1577916921.pdf**

then u can print pdf like this

```php
<iframe src="{{ asset($pdf->data) }}"  height="500" width="500" style="margin-Top :200px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: `GET http://localhost:8000/E:/laravel12/public/pdf/1578068735.pdf 404 (Not Found)` getting this error

Comment: already read and implemeted your solution but getting the above error